# What's the most efficient way in WebGL to find the min and max values of an RGBA float texture?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I'm storing floating-point gpgpu values in a webgl RGBA render texture, using only the r channel to store my data (I know I should be using a more efficient texture format but that's a separate concern).

Is there any efficient way / trick / hack to find the global min and max floating-point values **without** resorting to gl.readPixels?  Note that just exporting the floating-point data is a hassle in webgl since readPixels doesn't yet support reading gl.FLOAT values.

This is the gist of how I'm currently doing things:

```
if (!gl) {
    gl = renderer.getContext();
    fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    pixels = new Uint8Array(SIZE * SIZE * 4);
}

if (!!gl) {
    // TODO: there has to be a more efficient way of doing this than via readPixels...
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, data.rtTemp2.__webglTexture, 0);

    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        // HACK: we're pickling a single float value in every 4 bytes 
        // because webgl currently doesn't support reading gl.FLOAT 
        // textures.
        gl.readPixels(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        var max = -100, min = 100;

        for (var i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                var o = 4 * (i * SIZE + j);
                var x = pixels[o + 0];
                var y = pixels[o + 1] / 255.0;
                var z = pixels[o + 2] / 255.0;

                var v = (x <= 1 ? -1.0 : 1.0) * y;
                if (z > 0.0) { v /= z; }

                max = Math.max(max, v);
                min = Math.min(min, v);
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

(using a fragment shader that ouputs floating-point data in the following format suitable for UNSIGNED_BYTE parsing...

```
<script id="fragmentShaderCompX" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
uniform sampler2D source1;
uniform sampler2D source2;

uniform vec2 resolution;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;

    float v = texture2D(source1, uv).r + texture2D(source2, uv).r;
    vec4 oo = vec4(1.0, abs(v), 1.0, 1.0);

    if (v < 0.0) {
        oo.x = 0.0;
    }

    v = abs(v);
    if (v > 1.0) {
        oo.y = 1.0;
        oo.z = 1.0 / v;
    }

    gl_FragColor = oo;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I could not see the need for doing anything like that?
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm: One application would be finding the value range for tone mapping a HDR picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without compute shaders, the only thing that comes to mind is using a fragment shader to do that. For a 100x100 texture you could try rendering to a 20x20 grid texture, have the fragment shader do 5x5 lookups (with GL_NEAREST) to determine min and max, then download the 20x20 texture and do the rest on the CPU. Or do another pass to reduce it again. I don't know for which grid sizes it's more efficient though, you'll have to experiment. Maybe [this](http://www.lcg.ufrj.br/Cursos/GPUProg/GPGPU_Reductions) helps, or googling "reduction gpu".

Comment: GPGPU, Cuda stuff still not available for webGL. WebCL should do that but it's still in process of making.

Comment: @Abstract I wasn't talking about CUDA. I think our answers are almost the same, but rendering to a 1x1 framebuffer doesn't exploit the parallel nature of the GPU because there's only one fragment shader invocation. To keep as many GPU cores/texture units busy as possible you want to split up the work load such that you have multiple fragment shader invocations running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Render 1 vertex on 1x1 framebuffer and within shader sample whole previously rendered texture. That way you are testing texture on GPU which should be fast enough for real-time (or not?), however it is definitely faster than doing it on CPU, and the output would be min/max value.

I also ran across solution to try mipmap-ing texture and going through different levels.

These links might be helpful:

- http://www.gamedev.net/topic/559942-glsl--find-global-min-and-max-in-texture/
- http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/175692-most-efficient-way-to-get-maximum-value-in-texture

Hope this helps.